# Интернет магазин на Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby, интернет-магазин, cms, ruby-on-rails

Нужно сделать интернет магазин. Я разрабатываю на руби, поэтому стал копать в сторону cms интернет магазина на рельсах.

Нашел spree и его русский форк synergy, но они какие-то кривоватые и слабо подходят для русских/украинских реалий.

У кого был опыт создания магазина, есть ли смысл допиливать spree или лучше найти cms’ку на php, которая больше подходит, и настроить ее (php не знаю) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы действительно выучили Rails и знаете Ruby, то вопрос, лучше ли "допилить" движок на них у вас даже возникать не должен, ответ очевиден.

Если же вы не знаете PHP, то единственное, что вы можете сделать с движком на нём -- использовать "как есть".

Есть подходящий движок на PHP, который не надо допиливать, -- используйте его, иначе пишите/переписывайте на Rails, быстрее будет.